# Receiving specific text to be print on serial monitor

Tags: gsm, arduino-uno

I have my code which uses the ATMega328p and GSM Shield (Sim900).
The code shows that if the GSM receives specific text as `"FILL"` keyword, it will print on serial monitor as `"FILL in thr"`, also if the GSM receives "AUTOMATIC" keyword, it will print on serial monitor `"AUTOMATIC asd"`.

The code only works on the first on which is the FILL, but if i texted the keyword `AUTOMATIC`, nothing happens within the serial monitor.

Is there's something wrong within my code?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <string.h>

char str = 0;
char str1 = 0;
SoftwareSerial gsm = SoftwareSerial(2,3);
boolean gsmConnected = false;

void setup() 
{                

Serial.begin(9600);
gsm.begin(9600);
delay(300);

do    // initializing connection between gsm shield and gizduino
  {
    Serial.println("------------------------------------------");
    Serial.println("Initializing GSM Shield Connection..");
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Sending AT Command...");
    delay(500);
    gsm.println("AT");
    delay(500);
    if(gsm.available())
    {
      if(gsm.find("OK"))
      {
        Serial.println("GSM Shield replied 'OK'"); //gsm shield replied "OK"
        gsmConnected = true;
        gsm.print("\r");
        delay(500);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("Error!.. GSM Shield Not Communicating");
        gsmConnected = false;

      }
    }
  }

while(gsmConnected == false);
  Serial.println("Communicating.....");
  gsm.print("\r");
  delay(500);
  gsm.print("AT+CMGF=1\r"); // sms format = text mode
  delay(500);
  gsm.write(0x1A);
  Serial.println("READY!\r");

}
void loop()

{


//IF OWNER TEXTS FILL KEYWORD
if(gsm.available())
{
if(gsm.find("+639229639893") && gsm.find("FILL"))
{

Serial.println("FILL in thr");

}
}

//IF OWNER TEXTS AUTOMATIC KEYWORD
if(gsm.available())
{
if(gsm.find("+639229639893") && gsm.find("AUTOMATIC"))
{

Serial.println("AUTOMATIC asd");

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

changing your do{} to loop{} should help somewhat, be sure to remove the unnecessary print.ln's

there's a colon at the end of while loop conditional

Good practice to initiate the GSM before you initiate the serial.
Also to set junk data as mobile number when sharing the sketch

Answer (score 0):

Using gsm.find clears the buffer until it finds the keyword..based on your code...the first if statement search for the number and keyword "fill". So even if you text automatic.. the code will first search the keyword fill,, thus removing the keyword "automatic" from the buffer. It's better to store the serial data to a variable array first.